# Fade In only; not Fade Out - pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that fades in and out three objects, as see here...
http://ryanspahn.com/movies/testing.html

The code that drives that animation is pure JS and is seen below.  Though I do not want it to cycle through and only want each object to fade in/stay visible on the page.  Any idea how to change the below to do that?

```
var feedArr = Array("<img src='https://thingiverse-production-new.s3.amazonaws.com/renders/16/04/2d/b5/ed/smiley_face_thumb_small.jpg'>","<img src='http://www.mpaart.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/twitter-logo-round-50x50.png'>");
    var tweetCount = 0;

    function fadeOut(id,val){
      if(isNaN(val)){ val = 9;}
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity='0.'+val;
        //For IE
        document.getElementById(id).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';
      if(val>0){
        val--;
        setTimeout('fadeOut("'+id+'",'+val+')',90);
      }else{return;}
    }

    function fadeIn(id,val){
      if(isNaN(val)){ val = 0;}
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity='0.'+val;
        //For IE
        document.getElementById(id).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';
      if(val<9){
        val++;
        setTimeout('fadeIn("'+id+'",'+val+')',90);
      }else{return;}
    }

    function toogleFeeds(interval,val){
      var realIntravel=interval
      if(isNaN(val)){ val = 0;}
      if(val == 0){
        fadeOut('twitterFeed');
        val=1;
        realIntravel=1000;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('twitterFeed').innerHTML = feedArr[tweetCount];
        tweetCount++;
        if(tweetCount >=    feedArr.length){ tweetCount = 0;}
        fadeIn('twitterFeed');
        val=0;
      }
       setTimeout('toogleFeeds("'+interval+'",'+val+')',realIntravel);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried that `fadeIn` function?

Comment: the toggleFeeds function is intertwined with both fadeIn and fadeOut; not fully understanding what it does, thus I came here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this-

Of course this is only for 1 element, you can use same technique for multiple elements using class selectors or whatever.

The JS will look like this:

```
var val = 0;
var myInterval 

function fadeIn() {

    var id = "fadeInOnly";
    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    ele.style.opacity = '0.' + val;
    //For IE
    ele.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + val + '0)';
    if (val < 9) {
        val++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        return;
    }
}

function setFade(){
    myInterval = setInterval(fadeIn, 50);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<body onload="setFade();">
    <div id="feedWrapper">

        <img id="fadeInOnly" src='https://thingiverse-production-new.s3.amazonaws.com/renders/16/04/2d/b5/ed/smiley_face_thumb_small.jpg'>
    </div>
```

[fiddle example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/k4u3qvrk/8/)

Comment: thank you!  I'm not sure what you mean regarding how to get this working with additional images?  Appreciate any further insight and thanks again!

Comment: Now it is only working by ID (GetElementById) you need to replace it to getElementsByClass, add your class to all the elements and use a loop.

This link can guide you: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp